# Monotonicity of function $f(x)=-x^3+3x^2+9x-1$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am trouble understanding what I am doing wrong. This is my outcome, but the correct answers from my professor are being opposite of what I am getting.

$$f(x)=-x^3+3x^2+9x-1$$
$$f'(x)=-3x^2+6x+9 $$
$$x^2-2x-3 = 0$$
$$(x+1)(x-3)$$

Answer:

$f'(x)> 0 \ x\in(-\infty, -1)$

$f'(x)> 0 \ x\in(3, +\infty)$

$f'(x)< 0 \ x\in(-1, 3)$

Comment: What is confusing you?

Comment: $f'(0)=9>0$. The answer cannot be right.

Comment: You forgot the minus from line 2 to line 3

Comment: @Fakemistake I remove the `-` but I change the other `-` to `+`

Comment: $f'(x)=-3x^2+6x+9$ you drop the sign at the next step, which is fine when when it comes to finding zeros, but for the next bit you need to know the sign of the derivatives.  $f'(x) = -3(x+1)(x-3)$ would clear any confusion.

Comment: @Blitzer I see this in answers, https://i.imgur.com/pyHv9rm.png which is opposite of mine.

Comment: $(x+1)(x-3)$ is positive outside the interval of the roots, and negative inside this interval, so $f'(x==-(x+1)(x-3)$ is positive inside the interval of the roots, and negative outside.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f'(0)=9>0$, which contradicts case 3 of the answer.

When you factor the derivative, you should get
$$
f'(x)=-3x^2+6x+9=-3(x+1)(x-3)
$$

---

What is wrong in your attempt is that although $f'(x)=0$ and $(x+1)(x-3)=0$ have the same set of solutions,
$$
f'(x)\neq (x+1)(x-3)
$$

Comment: why is the $-3$ there when In 3rd step I got rid of it by dividing by $3$?

Comment: @bananaEater because you need the *equal sign* in $f'(x)=-3(x+1)(x-3)$. Both $f'(x)$ and $(x+1)(x-3)$ have the same zeros, namely, -1 and 3; but $f'(x)$ is not equal to $(x+1)(x-3)$.

Comment: @bananaEater: do you get it?